# Duplicate form using react final form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I have a form to add a new product. I would like to allow an user to add a new item by pressing `Add another item` in the same page. To show the same form duplicated and to be submitted all together.

I'm using react final form.
Any idea if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: This is easily done with setstate and localstorage, you can find the code of a todo list program and recreate it. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks AZ for your answer. I made a while ago a todo list app and im not sure how this can help. Basically a todo list app has a form and this add items to a list. What i want is to have a form which contain as many 'item's form' as the user wants. They user should be able to modify it at any moment and just when you press submit.. all the items will be saved.